# 'System.NotImplementedException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Tags: c#, .net-micro-framework

does anyone know how to fix this exception?
An unhandled exception of type 'System.NotImplementedException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

I'm using .NET microframework 4.1 and I have the "mscorlib" reference added but when I try to load a BMP image from the resources:

```
internal static Microsoft.SPOT.Bitmap GetBitmap(Resources.BitmapResources id)
{
    return Microsoft.SPOT.Bitmap(Microsoft.SPOT.ResourceUtility.GetObject(ResourceManager, id));
}

[System.SerializableAttribute()]
internal enum BitmapResources : short
{
    image = 24837,
}
```

I get that exception in the return sentence.

Stack trace:

> System.Resources.ResourceManager::GetObjectInternal\r\nS‌​ystem.Resources.Reso‌​urceManager::GetObje‌​ctFromId\r\nMicrosof‌​t.SPOT.ResourceUtili‌​ty::GetObject\r\nFEZ‌​TouchDriver_Example.‌​Resources::GetBitmap‌​\r\nFEZTouchDriver_E‌​xample.Program::Init‌​Graphics\r\nFEZTouch‌​Driver_Example.Progr‌​am::Main\r\n" string

Comment: Can you post the stack trace of the exception? Since there are multiple things that can be causing the exception on that line.

Comment: remove that comment and edit your question to include that stack trace.